# Retrieve videoId From JSON Using PHP

Tags: php

Link To JSON File: https://pastebin.com/gXcnNnUK
Code I've Tried So Far:

```
    $json = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($json as $data){
   echo $data['videoId'];
}
```

But it's not returning values. Is there any better approach to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 3, did you mean to iterate over $arr instead of $json?

```
$json = file_get_contents('json.json');
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($arr['contents']['sectionListRenderer']['contents']['2']['itemSectionRenderer']['contents'] as $pero){
$video_id_list .= $pero['compactVideoRenderer']['videoId'].',';
}
```

Comment: Damm, that's an typo, but i was also trying to do it via: foreach($json as $data){
   echo $data['videoId'];
}

Comment: but it doesn't work...can you tell me what's the issue?

Comment: Maybe ['contents'][2] instead of ['contents']['2']   ?

Comment: @Karan , your json file contains unicode characters which are malformed. 

use json_last_error_msg() to print the json_decode error message.

Your json_decode() line is returning null.

Comment: @Karan  Saving your json file in ANSI encoding worked for me.